# can you concatenate using compass mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to MongoDB. I would like to know if it is possible to concatenate two data from a collection using a compass.
I know it can be achieved using mongo shell, but why can't compass be used?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

image of the fields In this case I want to make `ENAME` concatenate with itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"make `ENAME` concatenate with itself"_?

Comment: @rickhg12hs select concat(ename, "-", ename) result column: John-John.
It is what I want to achieve but from the Compass. Ty.

Comment: Compass has a shell embedded at the bottom which you can use. If you're just editing a single document you should be able to do it manually in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB Compass, you can [`"$concat"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) strings in a projection of <kbd>Find</kbd>.
[image]